# What browsers support getElementById?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, getelementbyid

Is it safe to assume that `getElementById` works in every browser? If not, which ones do / do not support it?

Comment: Hopefully all, though older IEs might have some problems with it. On the other hand, older (and newer) IEs have truble with everything.

Comment: @KingKongFrog: How far back do you need to go?  When you go back far enough, things get hairier as far as compatibility goes.

Comment: I would like to know the minimum browser requirement for it to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All browsers support this however one issue I came upon in IE6&7 (adding to @Esailija's answer)

Do This:

```
<input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="5th Avenue" />
```

Don’t Do This:

```
<input type="text" name="full_address" id="address" value="5th Avenue" />
```

The reason you should do this is because in Internet Explorer, if you’re trying to target an element using `getElementById`, for some reason that browser will search the name attribute of certain elements on the page, in addition to the id. Assuming we’ve used the wrong method for coding the name and id values, the code blocks below will get the exact same result in IE7:

```
var fullAddress = document.getElementById("full_address");  
alert(fullAddress.value);  

var fullAddress = document.getElementById("address");  
alert(fullAddress.value);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's supported in all current browsers. It has been part of the DOM since DOM Level 1. So basically every browser which supports the document object modul (since IE 5.5) should support this method.

Source: [MDN (`document.getElementById`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById)

Answer (score 3):

Well it's supported very widely but at least two bugs I know of ([Both from jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js)):

- Blackberry returns elements that are not in the dom
- Elements are returned if their `name` matches the id (Opera, IE.. versions unknown)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for the minimum requirements for it to work, which I assume means the earliest browser where you can expect it to work, please check out this page:

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

According to it, you're on dicey ground pre IE-8 (they say "almost") and are good across the board with FireFox, Safari, Chrome and Opera.